# error: constructor HTable in class HTable cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am working the **hadoop hbase** . I just wrote a simple program to insert database database. When i run program i am getting following error:

InsertData.java:31: error: constructor HTable in class HTable cannot be applied to given types;
      HTable hTable = new HTable("emp", conn);

My code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;

import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;

public class InsertData {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      // Instantiating Configuration class
      Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();

      // Instantiating HTable class
      HTable hTable = new HTable(config, "emp");

      // Instantiating Put class
      // accepts a row name.
      Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("row1")); 

      // adding values using add() method
      // accepts column family name, qualifier/row name ,value
      p.add(Bytes.toBytes("personal"),
      Bytes.toBytes("name"),Bytes.toBytes("raju"));

      p.add(Bytes.toBytes("personal"),
      Bytes.toBytes("city"),Bytes.toBytes("hyderabad"));

      p.add(Bytes.toBytes("professional"),Bytes.toBytes("designation"),
      Bytes.toBytes("manager"));

      p.add(Bytes.toBytes("professional"),Bytes.toBytes("salary"),
      Bytes.toBytes("50000"));

      // Saving the put Instance to the HTable.
      hTable.put(p);
      System.out.println("data inserted");

      // closing HTable
      hTable.close();
   }
}
```

My help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which version of HBase you're using, but `HTable` has been deprecated for a while (see the [`HTable` API docs](https://hbase.apache.org/2.0/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html)) and is now purely an internal method. Instead, use [`Table`](https://hbase.apache.org/2.0/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Table.html) (ensure the version is in keeping with your HBase deployment):

You should depend on `org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:<VERSION>` (no need for any other HBase dependencies), and use the following methods:

```java
try {
  Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
  Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
  Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf("emp"));

  Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("row1"));
  p.add(Bytes.toBytes("personal"), Bytes.toBytes("name"),Bytes.toBytes("raju"));

  table.put(p);
} finally {
  table.close();
  connection.close();
}
```

Comment: I guess it's better to wait what HBase version he is using to define the `table` object.

Comment: I don't see why - if he's getting this error then he must be using a version of HBase to which my answer applies. `HTable` has been deprecated since HBase 1.0.0 (released five years ago this month), so no one should still be using it.

Comment: I understand!! Thank you for answer.